# Retrieve archived data

Tags: sql-server, archive

MSSQL database has previously been archived on another database. Approximately 70m rows (includes sales information.)

Now, I am asked to move this archived data to live database. Because, customer can't see order history older the 3 years.

Is it reasonable to do this? I think it will be slow. Are there other solutions?

- Live DB size : 250GB
- Archive DB size : 50GB
- CPU : 8 Core
- Memory : 64GB
- Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1)

Comment: Why can't the customer view the data in the archived db? Are they using an application that can only read from X table and the archived data is in Y table? What kind of abilities do you have to alter the database / table / procedures? Is high availability involved at all? (In case you have to deal with clustering and fail over, since you would have to ensure the instance failing over has enough will get enough power from the server hosting two active nodes on one server.)

Comment: Why would it be slow, given the data is suitably indexed in the first place?

Comment: @Shaulinator Yes and I have all the privileges (sysadmin). Not have high availability, just I using aws database migration service.

Comment: What is the workload like on the live DB? Off the top of my head, I think you could partition the table and integrate the old data into it. Alternatively you can create a view to join the old + new table together and still partition and index both tables. Columnstore indexes could help here too after the data is integrated.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Because there will be more data. The same two tablo, with 1 million records and 10 million records, returns the same query at different times. Not only this, but also the backup and index maintenance will it take a long time, am I wrong?

Comment: @Shaulinator The live database is being used by a website. Average - Batch Requests/sec : 367. Question is, should I be do? If no, I will appeal and probably use view option.

Comment: I feel like the application should be able to tell if the data they are requesting is X days old, go to Table1 otherwise go to Table2. A view more or less does that logic for you, but you have to beware of the performance impact and index accordingly. Columnstore indexes are also allowing people to run OLTP systems with a hybrid data warehouse piece attached for analysis. [Nonclustered columnstore index on a disk-based heap or B-tree index.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: According to your answer: the Live DB is way bigger than your Archive DB. Is it correct?

Comment: @Shaulinator Thenks, I testing columnstore index.

Comment: @AMG Yes, Live DB bigger.

Comment: In that case, I think adding 50 to 250 could make a non significant difference in performance...

Comment: Yes, I am convinced. I will transfer it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to implement the migration, I would ensure to have a good planned indexing.
First of all, move the historical data into history tables, having the same structure as the current working tables, then create indexes for big groups: For example, including a YEAR column and making sure this one is a mandatory filter when consulting the data.

As an option, you can create views to union historical with current data.
But if I were you, I would implement a whole HISTORICAL REPORT feature in the app; having an AGREEMENT with your customer about: HOW MANY YEARS are SET as the current data.

But, again, a good indexing plan, is one of the best practices you can do when restoring the old database.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no duplicate data to worry about, adding another 50 GB of data to a 250 GB database is not going to matter much, especially since the business requirements need the archived data in the live database.

Make sure you have good covering indexes. Perhaps you can import the historic data into a separate filegroup and then mark it as read-only. Perhaps you could use a table partition.

There are lots of options to think of. @AMG's answer covers some more business-related questions for your ongoing SLA as well.